# Multiple Conditional VB Macro in Excel, simple code modification required

Tags: vba, excel

I am using the following code to calculate the Balance from the data, Balance = Demand - collection

Code:

```
Sub DCB()
 Dim c As Range
 Dim lRow As Long
 lRow = 1
 Dim lRowLast As Long
 Dim lRowDiff As Long
 Dim lRowPortion As Long
 lRowPortion = 1
 Dim bFoundCollection As Boolean
 With ActiveSheet
  lRowLast = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
  Do
   Set c = .Range("A" & lRow)
   If c.Value Like "*COLLECTION*" Then
    bFoundCollection = True
   ElseIf bFoundCollection Then
    bFoundCollection = False
    If c.Value <> "BALANCE" Then
     c.EntireRow.Insert
     lRowLast = lRowLast + 1
     Set c = c.Offset(-1, 0)
     c.Value = "BALANCE"
    End If
    If c.Value = "BALANCE" Then
     .Range(c, c.Offset(0, 18)).Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
     .Range(c, c.Offset(0, 18)).Interior.Color = RGB(200, 200, 200)
     lRowDiff = c.Row - lRowPortion
     .Range(c.Offset(0, 3), c.Offset(0, 18)).FormulaR1C1 = _
      "=SUMIF(R[-" & lRowDiff & "]C1:RC1, ""*DEMAND*"", R[-" & lRowDiff & "]C:RC)" & _
      "-SUMIF(R[-" & lRowDiff & "]C1:RC1, ""*COLLECTION*"", R[-" & lRowDiff & "]C:RC)"
     lRowPortion = c.Row + 1
    End If
   End If
   lRow = lRow + 1
  Loop While lRow <= lRowLast + 1
 End With
End Sub
```

But I have some problems now, there are some conditions to be applied while calculating the balance. The columns U W Y are the Excess amount columns and the value of those columns are depended for I N S columns Balance amount respectively.

For example in I1 demand is 50 collection is 10 so as per the formula, Balance = Demand - collection hence 50-10 = 40, but there are values in U column, I want that the rest 40 amount should be deducted from the U column & balance should show 0 and the adjusted 40 amount should show on T1 column.

I want the above macro to be tweaked, at first the value of I2 should be checked if the value of I2 is greater than I1 then no problem, simple formula will apply B= D-C, but if value of I2 is less than I1 or the value of I2 is 0, then it will check if there are some value in U1, if have some value then that amount will be adjusted accordingly and adjusted amount should show in T1.

Similarly N column is associated with W column and adjusted amount will show on V column & S column is associated with Y column and adjusted amount will show on X column.
[image: Kindly check the image]

Comment: That is not VB.NET code.  It looks like some form of VBA

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want:

```
    Sub DCB()
 Dim c As Range
 Dim lRow As Long
 lRow = 1
 Dim lRowLast As Long
 Dim lRowDiff As Long
 Dim lRowPortion As Long
 lRowPortion = 1
 Dim bFoundCollection As Boolean
 Dim lRowLastDemand As Long


 With ActiveSheet
  lRowLast = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
  Do
   Set c = .Range("A" & lRow)
   If c.Value Like "*COLLECTION*" Then
    bFoundCollection = True
   ElseIf c.Value Like "*DEMAND*" Then
    lRowLastDemand = lRow
   ElseIf bFoundCollection Then
    bFoundCollection = False
    If c.Value <> "BALANCE" Then
     c.EntireRow.Insert
     lRowLast = lRowLast + 1
     Set c = c.Offset(-1, 0)
     c.Value = "BALANCE"
    End If
    If c.Value = "BALANCE" Then
     .Range(c, c.Offset(0, 18)).Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
     .Range(c, c.Offset(0, 18)).Interior.Color = RGB(200, 200, 200)
     lRowDiff = c.row - lRowPortion
     .Range(c.Offset(0, 3), c.Offset(0, 18)).FormulaR1C1 = _
      "=SUMIF(R[-" & lRowDiff & "]C1:RC1, ""*DEMAND*"", R[-" & lRowDiff & "]C:RC)" & _
      "-SUMIF(R[-" & lRowDiff & "]C1:RC1, ""*COLLECTION*"", R[-" & lRowDiff & "]C:RC)"
      If ((.Cells(lRow, 9)) > 0) And (.Cells(lRowLastDemand, 21) > 0) Then 'If Column I Balance > 0 and U has value
         .Cells(lRowLastDemand, 20) = .Cells(lRow, 9) 'T1 = Balance
         .Cells(lRowLastDemand, 21) = .Cells(lRowLastDemand, 21) - .Cells(lRow, 9) 'Adjust Col U
      End If
      If ((.Cells(lRow, 14)) > 0) And (.Cells(lRowLastDemand, 23) > 0) Then 'If Column N Balance > 0 and W has value
         .Cells(lRowLastDemand, 22) = .Cells(lRow, 14) 'V1 = Balance
         .Cells(lRowLastDemand, 23) = .Cells(lRowLastDemand, 23) - .Cells(lRow, 14) 'Adjust Col W
      End If
      If ((.Cells(lRow, 19)) > 0 And (.Cells(lRowLastDemand, 25) > 0)) Then 'If Column S Balance > 0 and Y has value
         .Cells(lRowLastDemand, 24) = .Cells(lRow, 19) 'X1 = Balance
         .Cells(lRowLastDemand, 25) = .Cells(lRowLastDemand, 25) - .Cells(lRow, 19) 'Adjust Col Y
      End If
     lRowPortion = c.row + 1
    End If
   End If
   lRow = lRow + 1
  Loop While lRow <= lRowLast + 1
 End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks quick reply

I have two problems 
when U is 100
1. After running your macro in I3 Balance I am getting Rs 40, I want that zero & T1 is 40 great and U1 is 60 great. 

I want the Balance I3 to be zero, because the Rs 40 amount has been adjusted with the value of U1. U W Ycolumn are the excess column, where consumer paid us in advance so that if he paid Rs 10 out of Rs 50 then we should have balance 40 but he has already deposited Rs 100 in advance for us thats why the Rs 40 need to be adjusted & should show on T1 & with your code thats working but I need the I3 column to show zero

Comment: 2. when U 1 is having value less than balance 
for example I1 Demand is 50 I2 collection is 10 & balance showed 40, but U1 having value 10 then that Rs 10 need to be adjusted U1 should be 0 but with your code I am getting U1 -30.

& I3 should be 50- collection 10 & adjusted 10 hence I 3 should be 30 & T1 should be 10

Same principle should apply for INS column associated with UWY column

Comment: Try stepping through the code using the debugger. You'll be able to see what the values are and how the if statements are working.

Comment: yes, but I don't understand VB coding, any help would have been better if possible... thanks